# performing facebook action using js sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am trying to perform an action 'recommend' in my facebook app.
the code in my index.html page is

```
  <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# aspxtesting: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/aspxtesting#">
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="539397469421547" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="item" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://localhost:4816/SageFrame/recommend.html" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Sample Item" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png" />
</head>
<div id="fb-root">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="button" runat="server" class="recommend" id="btnrecommend" value="recommend" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId: '539397469421547', // App ID
            status: true, // check login status
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
        });
    };

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
$('.recommend').click(function(){
FB.api('https://graph.facebook.com/me/aspxtesting:recommend?Item=http://localhost:4816/SageFrame/recommend.html&access_token=' + access_token + '', 'post', function(response) {
                if (!response || response.error) {
                    debugger;
                }
});
    } (document));
```

next i have the recommend.html page like

```
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> 
 <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# aspxtesting: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/aspxtesting#">
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="539397469421547" /> 
  <meta property="og:type"   content="item" /> 
  <meta property="og:url"    content="http://localhost:4816/SageFrame/recommend.html" /> 
  <meta property="og:title"  content="Sample Item" /> 
  <meta property="og:image"  content="https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png" /> 
  </head>
  <body></body>
  </html>
```

but i get the error 
The action you're trying to publish is invalid because it does not specify any reference objects. At least one of the following properties must be specified: item.

Comment: I have already gone through the documentation and most of the releated questions in stackoverflow but it didn't help me out.please help me out I have been stuck here since 3 days .

Comment: Its Item but i tried all alternatives Item as well as item

Answer (score 1):

Is the name of the item in your action configuration on facebook's side object `Item` or `item`? - you have `Item` in the call to Facebook's API but it's probably supposed to be `item`

Also, your `og:url` is set to a local URL, that won't work because Facebook's crawler needs to be able to reach the URL specified - if the URL doesn't work in [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) it won't work for actions you try to post either

Comment: I Changed the url to the url from live "https://srv5.sageframe.com/" but it now throws the error      Object at URL 'http://srv5.sageframe.com/recommend.html' is invalid because the configured 'og:type' of 'item' is invalid.   but the og:type in my recommend.html is item

Comment: You're missing the app's namespace in the `og:type` tag, in your case it should probably be `aspxtesting:item` - look at the [documentation on working with objects](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/defining-an-object/) for more details

Comment: Thanks @lgy for the response your suggestions worked out  but the action posted in the activity log only and not shown on the wall although its privacy is shwon as public

Comment: That's probably not a bug, not all actions are displayed prominently on timeline, they're surfaced automatically based on users' interactions with the actions - see the open graph documentation for details on where you can expect to see the actions, but bear in mind that not all actions are shown in ticker/news feed/timeline